What's the best visualization for an accuracy vs. enum list plot?
I have been training my DL model with different permutations of features and have been logging the results.
On on column is accuracy, just a scalar float.
On another column is a list of feature names used for training.
For each training run, my algo removes 1-3 features to see how it affects accuracy.
What's the best way to visualize or assess this such that I can remove features that negatively affect accuracy and keep features that positively affect accuracy?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sensitivity, specificity etc. and any weighted combinations of these suffer from all the same issues as accuracy, i.e., they all presume a very specific cost structure to decisions in the face of uncertainty - but they do not make the costs explicit. Better to work with probabilistic classifications and separate the decision aspect from them. Decisions need to take classifications and costs into account, and even if there are only two classes, there may well be more than two possible decisions

"What is the best way to visualize... this..." is one question, & it should be answerable; "... such that I can remove features that negatively affect accuracy and keep features that positively affect accuracy" is a different issue altogether.  The proper response to the latter would be a frame challenge that this approach should not be used.
